# How to display an particlar attribut in a selectbox in a ROO-generated application

Tags: spring-roo, html-select

I am currently getting myself into Spring-Roo and Spring-MVC. I have a fairly simple application that Roo generated for me. It consists of two entities, Record and Car, where Record has a reference to one particlar car.

After the initial setup I change one of the views to use field:select and display a combobox for selecting available cars and add them to a record.

```
<field:select field="car" id="c_de_recordcars_domain_Record_car" items="${cars}" path="/cars" />
```

This tag gives me a headache. As by now, the comboxbox displays all available cars...but it does so by displaying all attributes ( like "Car 1 Tue Jan 18 00:00:00 CET 2011 Friver1"). All I want is that the combobox only shows the name-attribute ("Car 1").

Within the tag, there is only the "itemValue"-Attribute but this only renders the value that is put into the request-param...I need something like "displayValue" where I can point to the java-field that is used to display.

How can I achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spring Roo (using Spring MVC functionality) offers use Application Conversion Service. You should implement method `Converter<Car, String> getCarConverter()` inside the `ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean`.

See [reference](http://www.springsource.org/roo/guide?w=base-web#conversion-service) for details.

Answer (score 11):

:) Just spent the whole Sunday struggling out of the same problem. 
   Simply add itemLabel="your field name from Car class".

```
<field:select field="car" 
              id="c_de_recordcars_domain_Record_car" 
              items="${cars}" 
            **itemLabel="CarName"**
              itemValue="id"
              path="/cars" />
```

Comment: This seems a lot cleaner than messing around with the converters.  You can also create your own getter method if you want to return something more complex than a single field.

Comment: In this way you can just post one label that for one to many is not sufficient

Answer (score 2):

For Spring roo 1.1.4 and above:

1. Read ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean.java carefully
2. Read ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean_Roo_ConversionService.aj carefully 
   You should find a static inner class  CarConverter  here.  It should have a very long 
   prefix. 
   You should find a installLabelConverters  method here, with a long prefix.
3. Copy the code CarConverter from 2  to 1, remove the long prefix. 
   Change the code inside convert() method, as what you like.
4. Copy the related import statements from 2 to 1.
5. Copy the code installLabelConverters method from 2 to 1, remove the long prefix.
6. Now save the file 1.
7. Start roo, let it update the .aj file.
8. Use "mvn tomcat:run" to compile and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add `toString` method in entity `Car`,in which return `Car`'s name field.
and verify this profile in `path:/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/tags/form/fields/select.tag`x
update all option content:

```
<option value="${item}">
    <spring:eval expression="item" />
</option>
```

to:

```
<option value="${item}">
    ${item}
</option>
```